# Permissions error while trying to use Ghost S3 Storage, Compatibility mode

Tags: amazon-s3, ghost-blog

We are using Docker to build a local environment for ghost on our apache server. Everything worked fine until trying to add s3 storage by following the docs at https://github.com/spanishdict/ghost-s3-compat

While attempting to run the container ghost complains:

`Message: Your installation folder contains some directories or files with incorrect permissions:`

Then lists all files and folders under `./content/storage/ghost-s3-compat/`
Run `sudo find ./ ! -path "./versions/*" -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;` and try again. When I  exec into the container and run that command and try to restart docker it says:

```
X Starting Ghost: undefined
A GhostError occurred.

Message: We detected a misuse. Please read the stack trace.
```

In the ghost logs it claims it cannot find my adapter in: `/var/www/ghost/content/adapters/storage/` or: `/var/www/ghost/versions/3.8.0/core/server/adapters/storage/`

The docs above said to put into `content/storage/` not `adapters/storage/` Has anyone run into this issue before and have an idea of how to fix? I have also recursively tried to give all files 664 permission but I get the error occurred message when trying to restart. The docs are very minimal and I can't find much on the matter. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
Ghost Version: 3.8.0
```

In my docker file I have

```
RUN mkdir /var/www/ghost/content/storage
RUN cp -r node_modules/ghost-s3-compat /var/www/ghost/content/storage/ghost-s3-compat
```

**production.config.json**

```
"storage": {
    "active": "ghost-s3",
    "ghost-s3": {
      "accessKeyId": "ACCESS_KEY__ID",
      "secretAccessKey": "SECERET_ACCESS_KEY_ID",
      "bucket": "BUCKET_NAME",
      "region": "REGION_SLUG"
    }
  },
  "paths": {
    "contentPath": "/var/www/ghost/content"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem seemed to arise from using the [ghost-s3-compat](https://github.com/spanishdict/ghost-s3-compat)

Looks like it hasn't been updated or maintained in awhile either. Nothing was wrong with the setup. Once I switched to the [ghost-storage-adapter-s3](https://github.com/colinmeinke/ghost-storage-adapter-s3) I was able to run ghost.

**Note:** I still had to run `sudo find ./ ! -path "./versions/*" -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;` to change the permission in order for this to work.

Hope this saves someone some troubles.